# Angular click not functioned

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind for frontend with angular and I am stuck on very strange issue. My click function not working on laptop screen and its working in mobile devices. I try to wrap with div etc but nothing works

My code

```
<section id="work">
    <div class="mx-auto w-40 md:w-80 lg:w-80 md:pt-64 lg:pt-64 flex flex-col items-center">
        <div class=" text-3xl md:text-5xl lg:text-5xl font-bold" (click)="changeindex(1)">
            Our Work
        </div>
        <div class="pt-5">
            <img src="assets/Saly-25.png" class="h-20">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mx-auto w-80 ">
        <div class="flex justify-between">
            <div *ngFor="let x of ourwork; let i = index"
                class="w-28 flex justify-center items-center align-middle" >
              <div (click)="changeindex(i)">
                <div [ngClass]="{'text-primary': activework == i}" class="font-semibold text-lg " (click)="changeindex(i)">
                    {{x.title}}
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="activework == i">
                    <img src="assets/Vector 35.png" class="w-4 ml-2 pt-1">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="mx-auto mt-8 w-4/5 flex align-middle justify-center">
        <img src="assets/crickrss.png" class="w-4/5">
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need nested click you can use like this.

```
<section id="work">
  <div
    class="mx-auto w-40 md:w-80 lg:w-80 md:pt-64 lg:pt-64 flex flex-col items-center">
    <div
      class="text-3xl md:text-5xl lg:text-5xl font-bold"
      (click)="changeIndex($event, 1)">
      Our Work
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mx-auto w-80">
    <div class="flex justify-between">
      <div
        *ngFor="let x of ourwork; let i = index"
        class="w-28 flex justify-center items-center align-middle">
        <div (click)="changeIndex($event, i)">
          <div
            [ngClass]="{ 'text-primary': activeWork === i }"
            class="font-semibold text-lg"
            (click)="changeIndex($event, i)">
            {{ x.title }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

In class component I added **$event.stopPropagation()**

```
ourwork: any[] = [
    { title: 'test1' },
    { title: 'test2' },
    { title: 'test3' },
    { title: 'test4' },
  ];
  activeWork: number = 0;

  changeIndex($event: any, e: any) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e);
    this.activeWork = e;
  }
```

In this case each click works fine.